# Convolution of real with complex signal

Tags: convolution, complex

Let $x[n]$ be real signal and $y[n]=\exp(j3\pi n)$ be a complex signal

Would the convolution between those two signals be $$x[n] * \Re(y[n]) + jx[n]*\Im(y[n])$$?

Answer (score 1):

Discrete convolution is a linear operation, so yes

$$\begin{align*}x[n]*y[n] &= (x*y)[n]\\
\\
&= \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} x[m]y[n-m] \\
\\
&= \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} x[m]\Re(y[n-m])+ jx[m]\Im(y[n-m]) \\
\\
&= \left[\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} x[m]\Re(y[n-m])\right] + \left[\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} jx[m]\Im(y[n-m])\right] \\
\\
&= x[n]*\Re(y[n])+jx[n]*\Im(y[n])\\
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes so you can see this even simpler with **distribution** of convolution as:

$$
\begin{align} 
x[n] \star y[n] & = x[n] \star \left( \Re \{ y[n] \} + j   ~~ \Im \{ y[n] \} \right) \\
&= x[n] \star \Re \{ y[n] \} + j ~~ x[n] \star \Im \{ y[n] \} 
\end{align}$$